# How to write an allocatable array in a derived type using namelists?

Tags: io, fortran, fortran2003, derived-types

I am having trouble writing an allocatable array nested in a derived type using namelists. A minimal example is shown below. How can I modify the program to have the allocatable array inside the derived type work as though it were not nested?

```
program test

    implicit none

    type struct_foo
        integer, allocatable :: nested_bar(:)
    end type struct_foo

    integer, allocatable :: bar(:)
    type(struct_foo) :: foo
    ! namelist / list / foo, bar
    namelist / list / bar

    allocate(bar(5))
    bar = [1:5]

    allocate(foo%nested_bar(5))
    foo%nested_bar=[1:5]

    write(*,list)

end program test
```

With the foo commented out of the namelist, it works just fine, producing the output:

```
 &LIST
 BAR     =           1,           2,           3,           4,           5
 /
```

With foo included, the program fails to compile:

```
>> ifort -traceback test_1.f90 -o test && ./test
test_1.f90(20): error #5498: Allocatable or pointer derived-type fields require a user-defined I/O procedure.
    write(*,list)
--------^
compilation aborted for test_1.f90 (code 1)
```

Comment: Can you tell us which compiler you are using?

Comment: ifort (IFORT) 15.0.3 20150408

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, you need to provide a user defined derived type I/O (UDDTIO) procedure.  This is required for input/output of any object with an allocatable or pointer component.

How the object of derived type is formatted in the file is completely under the control of the UDDTIO procedure.

An example, using a very simple output format, is below.  Typically a UDDTIO procedure implementing namelist output would use an output format that was consistent with the other aspects of namelist output and typically there would also be a corresponding UDDTIO procedure that was then able to read the formatted results back in.

```
module foo_mod
  implicit none

  type struct_foo
    integer, allocatable :: nested_bar(:)
  contains
    procedure, private :: write_formatted
    generic :: write(formatted) => write_formatted
  end type struct_foo
contains
  subroutine write_formatted(dtv, unit, iotype, v_list, iostat, iomsg)
    class(struct_foo), intent(in) :: dtv
    integer, intent(in) :: unit
    character(*), intent(in) :: iotype
    integer, intent(in) :: v_list(:)
    integer, intent(out) :: iostat
    character(*), intent(inout) :: iomsg

    integer :: i

    if (allocated(dtv%nested_bar)) then
      write (unit, "(l1,i10,i10)", iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg)   &
          .true.,  &
          lbound(dtv%nested_bar, 1),  &
          ubound(dtv%nested_bar, 1)
      if (iostat /= 0) return
      do i = 1, size(dtv%nested_bar)
        write (unit, "(i10)", iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg)  &
            dtv%nested_bar(i)
        if (iostat /= 0) return
      end do
      write (unit, "(/)", iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg)
    else
      write (unit, "(l1,/)", iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) .false.
    end if
  end subroutine write_formatted
end module foo_mod

program test
  use foo_mod

  implicit none

  integer, allocatable :: bar(:)
  type(struct_foo) :: foo
  namelist / list / foo, bar

  allocate(bar(5))
  bar = [1:5]

  allocate(foo%nested_bar(5))
  foo%nested_bar=[1:5]

  write (*,list)
end program test
```

Use of UDDTIO obviously requires a compiler that implements this Fortran 2003 language feature.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. Is there a particular reason why the language doesn't allow namelist to write directly from an allocatable within a derived type?

Comment: There isn't an obvious formatted representation of the allocation status of an allocatable component (or the semantics and association status of a pointer component).  Perhaps the component will always be allocated - in which case there's no need to represent an unallocated condition, perhaps the lower bound will always be one, etc.  It gets even more complicated when you consider polymorphic components and components with deferred length parameters.

Comment: Thanks again, Ian. One final question: why doesn't write (unit, "(i10)", iostat=iostat, iomsg=iomsg) produce a line break after writing i10? How can the line break be achieved within the UDDTIO?

Comment: Child input/output statements (those called as part of UDDTIO processing) do not automatically advance to the next record - they are always considered non-advancing (ADVANCE='NO') input/output statements.

Comment: Is there a way to produce a linebreak with the child i/o?

Comment: A new record can be started explicitly using the slash edit descriptor, as in the example.